# CSS - non-breaking space between img and text

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask for help with this task:
I would like to have a non-breaking-space between img and a piece of text. But the problem is, that sometimes the line between image and text breaks up even if the non-breaking-space appears. 
Where am I wrong?

Here is the JsFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/cj7Lp1vy/9/

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <!-- some content -->
        <div class="cl">
            <img src="obrazky/plocha.png">&nbsp;Plocha: 11 m<sup>2</sup>
            <img src="obrazky/pocet_pokoju.png">&nbsp;Pokoje: 2
            <img src="obrazky/rekonstrukce.png">&nbsp;Rekonstrukce: ne
            <img src="obrazky/okna.png">&nbsp;Okna: stará
            <img src="obrazky/topeni.png">&nbsp;Topení: dřevo
            <img src="obrazky/typ_stavby.png">&nbsp;Typ stavby: dřevo            
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    width:235px;
    min-height:110px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding:15px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin:0px 12px 24px 12px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
#child {
    position:relative;
}
.cl {
    clear:both;
}
img {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:16px;
}
```

Comment: You added your fiddle to a code block, so we cannot see it. Furthermore you should add your code to the question so that in the future if we loose the code in the fiddle it is backed up in your question for others to understand what the question is.

Comment: You could try adding `img {display:inline-block; margin-right:5px;}`

Comment: And there always is a non-breaking space, the line just breaks after it.

Comment: Since it is clearly a sort of a list why don't you format it as it is intended in HTML with <ul> and <li>? You could set the image via css classes as non-repeating background images of the <li> elements and make some padding on the left side of the li to have the required distance from image to text... just as a side note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going wrong because the Unicode specification for NBSP says that there shouldn't be a line break **after** the character. it doesn't stop there being one before the character.

To work around this, wrap the `<img>` and the `&nbsp;` in a span and give the span the styling `white-space:nowrap;`